# Laravel DB Insert Error: Allowed Memory Size Exhausted

Tags: php, laravel, memory-limit

I'm running into an issue when trying to insert ~20K records into my DB. I notice that even though I'm echoing inside my foreach loop, I'm not getting anything outputted in the command line. Instead, I get an error after inserting ~9440 records relating to...

> `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 91 bytes) in
>   /Users/me/Sites/Laravel/database/connection.php on line 293`

Here is my code (tried using both Eloquent and Fluent):

```
<?php

class Process_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public function action_migrate()
    {
        $properties = DB::table('raw_properties')->get('id');
        $total = count($properties);

        foreach ($properties as $x => $p) {
            $r = RawProperty::find($p->id);
            $count = $x + 1;

            $prop_details = array(
                'column' => $r->field,
                // Total of 21 fields
            );

            DB::table('properties')->insert($prop_details);

            echo "Created #$count of $total\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error depicts that your PHP script has exhausted memory limit due to insufficient memory allocated for script.

You need to increase memory_limit using the ini_set function
e.g ini_set('memory_limit','128M');

Comment: I just hit this problem to, increasing the memory limit is a quick fix. A much better solution is to turn off query logging as recommended by @Erik below

Answer (score 34):

The accepted answer is fixing the symptom rather then the problem. The problem is the Laravel query log (in memory) is eating all your RAM when you execute such a large # of queries. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776710/221745

Or, in brief, turn off query logging via:

```
DB::disableQueryLog()
```

Before executing 20k queries

Comment: I agree. While inserting 1M lines in a table 2G wasn't enough, but DB::disableQueryLog() fixed it for me.

Comment: thanks I'd def prefer to fix the problem rather than the symptom

Comment: Does this have to be enabled again to have Querylogging or is this for the current script?

Comment: In laravel 5 its disabled by default.  So if you have memory problem you must do the opposite to inspect generated queries : `DB::enableQueryLog(); [...] dd(DB::getQueryLog());`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27753889/2152973

Answer (score 0):

I did the DB::disableQueryLog() and continued to get the error.  I ended up Pausing Telescope from recording the queries.  You can do this from the telescope web interface > queries > Click the Pause Icon.