# Laravel download pdf in public folder

Tags: laravel

I have a a pdf in public/downloads.  I want to just link to it and have it download or open in browser.  I tried hitting `http://localhost:8000/downloads/brochure.pdf` in the browser but I just get a white screen with no errors.  In Chrome DevTools > Network, it says the request was canceled.  I'm inserting the URL via javascript so I can't use URL::to or link_to() like other answers on here have suggested.

Note:  When I link to a css file in the same fashion as the brochure.pdf, the css appears in the browser.

Comment: Should work as it is. How's the file permissions? Try pointing your browser to http://localhost:8000/robots.txt. What do you see?

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942497/why-dont-large-files-download-easily-in-laravel).

Answer (score 11):

Path to file can be achieved like:

```
public function getDownload(){

        $file = public_path()."/downloads/info.pdf";
        $headers = array('Content-Type: application/pdf',);
        return Response::download($file, 'info.pdf',$headers);
    }
```

function will download file from : 'project/public/downloads' folder.

(don't forget to set-up routes and controller by yourself)

Comment: Laravel 8:      return response()->download($file, 'info.pdf', $headers);

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have stored the file in the public folder under a folder called file and the file name is called download.pdf, (public/file/download.pdf);

This is a minimal working alternative without Laravel facade.

Optional arguments can be added to `->download()`
method: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#file-downloads

Working with php 7.4+

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

public function downloadPdfFile() : BinaryFileResponse
{
     return response()->download(public_path('file/download.pdf'));
}
```