# Laravel Download and Redirect

Tags: php, laravel

How can I download a PDF file and Redirect the another Route in Laravel 5.1.

For Download a File

return response()->download($pathToFile);

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012832/laravel-download-pdf-in-public-folder

Answer (score 0):

That's how I have downloading a file in browser and it gets downloaded.

```
  $fileName = "file.pdf";
       if (file_exists($fileName)) {
           header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
           header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
           header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($fileName).'"');
           header('Expires: 0');
           header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
           header('Pragma: public');
           header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fileName));
           readfile($fileName);
           //You can redirect to any route from here.
           exit;
       }
```