# Unable to download file from s3 using return response()->download($file);

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I am uploading files to`s3` I want it to download securely using following code in my controller, but it's not working.

I am using Laravel 5.5 and files visibility is not public on `s3`.

```
if( Storage::disk('s3')->exists($file_path) ) {
      $file =  Storage::disk('s3')->get($file_path);
      return response()->download($file);
}

abort(404, 'File not found.');
```

It's giving me this error

```
is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given
...
/home/vagrant/spark-etr/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php:36
#1 /home/vagrant/spark-etr/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php(36): is_file('\\xFF\\xD8\\xFF\\xE0\\x00\\x10JFIF\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x00\\x00...')
#2 /home/vagrant/spark-etr/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/BinaryFileResponse.php(94): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\File->__construct('\\xFF\\xD8\\xFF\\xE0\\x00\\x10JFIF\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x00\\x00...')
#3 /home/vagrant/spark-etr/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/BinaryFileResponse.php(53): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\BinaryFileResponse->setFile('\\xFF\\xD8\\xFF\\xE0\\x00\\x10JFIF\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x00\\x00...', 'attachment', false, true)
#4 /home/vagrant/spark-etr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ResponseFactory.php(125): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\BinaryFileResponse->__construct('\\xFF\\xD8\\xFF\\xE0\\x00\\x10JFIF\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x00\\x00...', 200, Array, true, 'attachment')
```

The file is on `s3` since I am checking for exists before downloading.

#### Update

Dumping the `$file` var gives me binary like this

[image]

Please help

Comment: What do you get when you call dd($file);?

Comment: it gives me binary data, looks like file itself

Comment: what is the content type of the `file`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
if( Storage::disk('s3')->exists($file_path) ) {
      $file =  Storage::disk('s3')->get($file_path);

      $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'your_content_type', 
        'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
        'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename={$yourFileName}",
        'filename'=> $yourFileName
     ];

    return response($file, 200, $headers);
}
```

**Update**

You can read more about downloading `large` files 
[Why don't large files download easily in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942497/why-dont-large-files-download-easily-in-laravel)

Comment: this is working but file size can go upto 100mb or more, will it be efficent. I am afread it will give `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 5242880 bytes exhausted`

Comment: Im not sure you will ever see that :)

Comment: @Saqueib i have pasted a link to help you with `large` files

Comment: Dont u also need to include Content-Length?

Answer (score 2):

Build the response yourself:

```
    $file = ''; // what you got from S3
    $mimeType = 'text/plain'; // or whatever the mime type is
    $fileName = 'example.txt';

    $headers = [
        'Content-type'        => $mimeType,
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"',
        'Content-Length'      => sizeof($file),
    ];

    return response($file, 200, $headers);
```

... or research on how to download streams.