# Best way to process large database with Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel-4, database-performance

**The database**

I'm working with a database that has pretty big tables and it's causing me problems. One in particular has more than 120k lines.

**What I'm doing with it**

I'm looping over this table in a `MakeAverage.php` file to merge them into about 1k lines in a new table in my database.

**What doesn't work**

Laravel doesn't allow me to process it all at once even if I try to `DB::disableQueryLog()` or  or a `take(1000)` limit for example. It returns me a blank page every time even if my error reporting was enabled (kind of like [this](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=11330)). Also, I had no Laravel log file for this. I had to look in my php_error.log (I'm using MAMP) to realize that it was actually a memory_limit problem.

**What I did**

I increased the amount of memory before executing my code by using `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M')`. (It's bad practice, I should do it in php.ini.)

**What happened?**

It worked! However, Laravel thrown me an error because the page didn't finished to load after 30s because of the large amount of data.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't looping `$table` properly in `average.php`.  Can you post the relevant code you have in there as well as the code you are using to create `$table`?

Comment: Check your error logs if you have not already - this may be an error instead of a memory limit. You *usually* get an error on memory limit issues instead of a blank page - I'm guessing error reporting is off?

Comment: One small thing, but I don't think it's your entire issue...  `Trialdata::all()->get()` will not work and should be `Trialdata::all()`.  That should have thrown an error because it did for me.

Comment: @fideloper My error reporting is on. My log says:
`exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Use of undefined constant memory_limit - assumed 'memory_limit''`

Comment: @user1669496 Indeed, I made a mistake in writing the code here but my original file was fine. Even when I add `->get()` it does not throw me an error, just like if Laravel stops after reading `::all()`. Everything written after isn't processed.

Comment: Interesting. Some googling confirms that others have gotten white screens on memory errors. I should mention that the only other time I've gotten white screens with no errors was when PHP attempted to use modules which weren't loaded (for example GD, curl, PDO)

Comment: That doesn't sound like a problem with the actual memory limit.  It sounds like you are trying to call a constant called `memory_limit` and it's undefined.  Try defining `memory_limit` as a constant and see what happens.  `define('memory_limit', '128M');`

Comment: @user1669496 When I define the memory limit, I come across the blank page but no error is logged at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What I will do**

After spending some time on this issue and looking at other people having similar problems (see:  [Laravel forum](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=11330), [19453595](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453595/laravel-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-on-basic-query), [18775510](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775510/laravel-eloquent-memory-leak-retrieving-the-same-record-repeatedly) and [12443321](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443321/laravel-db-insert-error-allowed-memory-size-exhausted)), I thought that maybe PHP isn't the solution.

Since, I'm only creating a `Table B` from the average values of the `Table A`, I believe that a SQL is going to fits best my needs as it's clearly faster than PHP for that type of operation (see: [6449072](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449072/doing-calculations-in-mysql-vs-php)) and I can use functions such as `SUM`, `AVERAGE`, `COUNT` and `GROUP_BY` ([Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/func-op-summary-ref.html)).