# Laravel 4, PHPUnit and DB::getQueryLog() always empty

Tags: laravel-4, phpunit, eloquent

I have a phpunit test that does some query stuff and then:

```
$results = $thingy::where("finder_id", "=", "37");
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
dd($queries);
```

but $queries always returns an empty array

Config::get('app.debug') is true.

I have tried:

```
DB::enableQueryLog() 
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog()
```

with no luck. I have also tried various event listeners like:

```
Event::listen("illuminate.query", function($query, $bindings, $time, $name){
    \Log::sql($query."\n");
    \Log::sql(json_encode($bindings)."\n");
});
```

What else could be causing this?

EDIT: To eliminate PHPUnit as the cause, I setup a test route with a known working model

```
Route::get('fndr',function() {
    $customer = new Customer;
    $results = $customer->first();
    var_dump($results->NAME);
    $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
    dd($queries);

});
```

Still $queries is empty.

Comment: The logging takes place in the `Illuminate\Database\Connection` class. Within the `run` method of that class there is a call to the `logQuery` method. Try determining if the logging is actually being called and executed correctly. Your code is otherwise correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer helped me:

[here][How to get the query executed in Laravel 5 ? DB::getQueryLog returning empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr)

The Some Tips 1  Multiple DB connections
If you have more than one DB connection you must specify which connection to log

To enables query log for my_connection:

```
DB::connection('my_connection')->enableQueryLog();
```

To get query log for my_connection:

```
print_r(
   DB::connection('my_connection')->getQueryLog()
);
```

Both `enbleQueryLog()` and `getQueryLog()` needed to specify the connection name

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I needed to specify the name of the connection to use. I'm assuming it uses the default connection otherwise.

```
$queries = DB::connection('name_of_connection')->getQueryLog();
dd($queries);
```