# Laravel Query Builder select a column with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1, query-builder

I have four arrays and a one variable like below.

$jptypes = ["26","27"]

$jvalues = ["57","62"]

$jbranches = ["33","63"]

$jstream = ["2","2"]

$jmarks = 10

I want to collect **employees** with those matching arrays and value.

```
 $empsarr = DB::table('otc_employee_qualifications')
            ->whereIn('emp_qualifctn_type',$jptypes)
            ->whereIn('qualification_value',$jvalues)
            ->whereIn('emp_qualifctn_branch',$jbranches)
            ->whereIn('emp_qualifctn_stream',$jstream)
            ->where('qualification_mark','>=',$jmarks)
            ->distinct()
            ->lists('employee_id');

  return $empsarr;
```

[image]

But whereIn method will not checking  both values. its in **OR** case.

I want to check both the values in the array at once.

how can i solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you getting any error while running the query ? can you explain what is the OR case you mentioned ?

Comment: @Jishad P can you please tell me which records you want to be in the output ( specify the emp_eual_id s )

Comment: well, if you are unsure on laravel queries, try to use [query log](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#query-logging) but you had to activate it for [laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr). However, there are tools - which i didn't try yet - like [laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).