# Select with advanced where clauses and timestamp using Carbon and DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have a code to generate a SQL query from a table.
I want to select items that exist between dates and a true value in another field.

DB use in construction and Carbon facades, following advice on how to work with Carbon in laravel 5.

But I do not get the effect I returns all rows

```
private function runBids() {
      $dt = Carbon::parse(Config::get('constants.start_lot'));
      $start = $dt->toDateTimeString();  // 2006-05-08 08:34:59
      $end   = $dt->addDay()->startOfDay(); // 2006-05-09 00:00:00

      $lots = DB::table('lots')
               ->select('id')
               ->where('end',false)
               ->where('end_auction', '<=', $end)
               ->where('end_auction', '=>', $start)  // Not work. Return 0 results
     // if comment  ->where('end_auction', '=>', $start) result 39 results with date 
     // between dates 
     // (start it's date of first element of table order by end_auction) 
               ->get();
      $lots_id = array();
      foreach ($lots as $value){
         $lots_id[] = $value->id;
      }
      dd($lots_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all seems correct, except for the operator used on the `$start` parameter. You have

```
->where('end_auction', '=>', $start)
```

And you should have

```
->where('end_auction', '>=', $start)
```

Notice the difference between `=>` and `>=`. The first throws a MySQL error. You could try to wrap that code around a `try ... catch` block, and check the exception message.

You can also log the executed queries using [one of this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr), to check the executed query whenever you don't get the expected results.

Comment: Oh my God... hours about this question for a mistake. A lot of thanks. And other thanks for your tips of enable query log on Laravel