# Laravel one to many relation

Tags: php, laravel, loading, relationship, eager

Cannot seem to find what I am doing wrong anymore after trying to get something else to work using polymorphic relations.. I have two tables setup:

Payments:

```
- id
- name
- etc..
```

Deposits:

```
- id
- payment_id
- name
- etc..
```

My model relationships:

Payment:

```
public function deposits()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Deposit::class);
}
```

Deposit:

```
public function payments()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Payment::class);
}
```

Now I have one record in each table for testing purposes. I am trying to eager load the payments when displaying the deposits:

For example:

```
$deposits = Deposit::with('payments')->get();
```

This does not return the payment that is associated with it, just returns `null` for the relation. In my table the payment_id is 1, just as the id in the payments table. To my recollection, this should work. What am I missing?

Edit, the getQueryLog returns this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(52) "select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? limit 1" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1) } ["time"]=> float(0) } [1]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(24) "select * from `deposits`" ["bindings"]=> array(0) { } ["time"]=> float(0) } [2]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(53) "select * from `payments` where `payments`.`id` in (?)" ["bindings"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["time"]=> float(0) } }
```

[image]

Comment: You need to specify the foreign key in your `payments()` function as the second argument since laravel assumes the foreign key is `table1name_table2name_id`. So in your case it would be `return $this->belongsTo(Payment::class, 'payment_id');`

Comment: I take that back, it's `return $this->hasMany(Deposit::class, 'payment_id');`. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Comment: @Andrew laravel assume keys 'ModelName_id`, table name has nothing to do in that case.  **Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with _id**

Comment: @xdevnull That is correct according to the laravel docs. I'm a little rusty on my laravel skills but that's no excuse.

Comment: Yup it should work without specifying the foreign key

Comment: @Ron What do u get when executing this ```Payement::all()```

Comment: That works, also with eager loading the deposits. It's the other way around that isn't working, the Deposit::with('payments')

Comment: @RonBrouwers ```Deposit::all()``` works too?

Comment: Yup, it's very strange... It all works except for the relations belongsTo it seems. Might be something else wrong somewhere in the code probably, since it seems the code above should simply work as expected..

Comment: Okay let's log the sql query for ```relationship```, Run this code after the relationship eager loading (that doesn't work) ```var_dump(DB::getQueryLog())```

Comment: Then you should probably specify the foreign key in the `belongsTo` relationship as well. And check if the appropriate Payment::class is used.. in the code.. Check the `use` statements at the top of your Deposit Model

Comment: That getQueryLog returns nothing, not sure how to use it, never used it before. With or without the `use` statements it doesn't work. But I will look for more info on that getQueryLog :)

Comment: @RonBrouwers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr

Comment: Thanks, was already checking out that question. Yeah it returns something. will edit it in the question

Comment: Added a picture of the getQueryLog results

Comment: So appearantly it checked for a "payments_id". So I guess we now know what's wrong.. Thanks for all the help lol, uess I should specify the foreign key after all...

Comment: @ron-brouwers You missed my comment above.. :)

Comment: @RonBrouwers Add answer to your question and mark it as "Accepted".

Comment: Working on it :P Still trying to figure out why I have to specify the foreign key because it should work. PS. Even when specifying the foreign key, it's still looking for `payments_id`. Ofcourse I can change my database column but I like figuring out why stuff is "unexpected" like this..

Comment: How do you know it is searching for `payments_id`?

Comment: Good question, I don't, I assumed.. I thought so because of the queryLog results. I changed my database column name in deposits to `payments_id` and it worked

Comment: Checked again using the foreign key and it works now, will add my answer now but still check as to why this is happening, I shouldn't have to add it (not that it matters ofcourse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my relation in my Deposit model and it works:

```
public function payment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Payment::class, 'payment_id');
}
```

Still figuring out why I have to add it, since it should work without it as well.