# Laravel 5 Eloquent: How to get raw sql that is being executed? (with binded data)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Im trying to figure out how to get the raw sql query being executed including the binded data in it. Here is what ive got:

```
\DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
$query = \DB::getQueryLog();
$lastQuery = end($query);
```

And here is what the result looks like:

```
array(3) {
  ["query"]=>
  string(57) "select * from `table_1` where `field_1` = ? limit 1"
  ["bindings"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(34) "xyz"
  }
}
```

So how do I get a dump of a full sql query like this (the good old fashioned way)?

```
select * from `table_1` where `field_1` = 'xyz' limit 1
```

Thanks

Comment: it is easy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr

Answer (score 8):

You may want to check out the [Laravel debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar). I wouldn't develop a Laravel app without it. It will give you a breakdown of all queries (including repeated queries and ajax queries), with the speed they executed at and a note to the line in the controller/method that called them. (It provides TONS more info as well, such as views, gates, routes, etc.)

Also, Laravel has a `toSql()` method that you can use instead of your example. **It will only show you the prepared statement as your example does**, but it's at least a little cleaner. If you use `toSql()`, you have to apply it before you execute the query though.

```
$foo = Foo::where('bar', 'baz');
$foo_sql = $foo->toSql();
$foo->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this in your routes Folder :

```
\Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query) {
    Log::info( json_encode($query->sql) );
    Log::info( json_encode($query->bindings) );
    Log::info( json_encode($query->time)   );
});
```

Log::info() ==> will log the SQL query in your storage/logs/laravel.log file

var_dump() ==>  will display in the API call output

Comment: Awesome. Saved me some quality time.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add event listener for query :

```
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query)
{
    var_dump($query);
});
```

or

```
$results = User::where('id',$id)->toSql();
dd($results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to get the queries from *Laravel Debugbar*:

```
$queries = debugbar()->getCollector('queries');  
$statements = $queries->collect()['statements'];
dd($statements);
```