# Laravel Eloquent display query log

Tags: php, laravel

```
use App\Order;
 
public function show(Order $order) {
    $data = $order->all();
    return dd($order->getQueryLog());
```

Is there any way to display the query built by Eloquent in Laravel?

I tried `getQueryLog();` but its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the query executed in Laravel 5 ? DB::getQueryLog returning empty array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr)

Answer (score 182, accepted):

First you have to enable query log
it can be done using

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
```

then you can use below code to see the query log

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```

if you want to see the last executed query

```
$last_query = end($queries);
```

to know more about logging see this https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging

Example

```
public function show(Order $order){
    \DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
    $data = $order->all();
    $queries = \DB::getQueryLog();

    dd($queries);
}
```

Comment: is this only for DB query? I'm using eloquent, and I want to see laravel's query

Comment: it will work for eloquent as well, check  the updated answer I have shown in the example

Comment: oh i didnt know I need to put enableQueryLog(); before my query, i put it behind lol, thx a lot!

Answer (score 85):

To see the query logs in `laravel.log` file, update `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
namespace App\Providers;

use DB;
use Log;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        DB::listen(function($query) {
            Log::info(
                $query->sql,
                [
                    'bindings' => $query->bindings,
                    'time' => $query->time
                ]
            );
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Wow, I wish I knew about this years ago. So helpful! Thanks.

Comment: Great helpful bro

Answer (score 32):

To use `getQueryLog()` you need to enable it first:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
DB::getQueryLog();
```

If you want to see real queries, you can use [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), it will show all real queries Laravel created during current request.

Sometimes `->toSql()` is also useful.

Comment: Much more succinct.

Comment: Wheere does this go?

Answer (score 9):

Working on 5.6, something like this in AppServiceProvider::boot()

```
    // Log all DB SELECT statements
    // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
    if (!app()->environment('testing') && config('app.log_sql')) {
        DB::listen(function ($query) {
            if (preg_match('/^select/', $query->sql)) {
                Log::info('sql: ' .  $query->sql);
                // Also available are $query->bindings and $query->time.
            }
        });
    }
```

Then in config/app.php, just so it's easy to enable/disable from amending the .env

```
    'log_sql' => env('LOG_SQL'),
```

All credit to: https://arjunphp.com/laravel-5-5-log-eloquent-queries/

And this can be parsed for unique queries with:

```
    grep ") sql:" laravel.log | sed -e "s#.*select\(.*\)\[\]#select\1#" | sort -u
```

Answer (score 6):

write this before the query DB::enableQueryLog();

```
DB::enableQueryLog();

$data = $order->all();

$query = DB::getQueryLog();

dd($query);
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old question, but it might help others that had the same issue I had.

If you use other connection than the default one, you should specify it to get the query log properly.

```
\DB::connection('YourConnection')->enableQueryLog();
$test = MyModel::all();
$queries = \DB::connection('YourConnection')->getQueryLog();
dd($queries);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this package https://github.com/supliu/laravel-query-monitor

After installing, open the terminal and run the command:

```
php artisan laravel-query-monitor
```

All queries executed by Eloquent will be displayed in real time

Comment: not sure why.. but seems not working

Answer (score 3):

Query Execution

```
\Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query) {          
            $sql = $query->sql; 
            $time = $query->time;
            $connection = $query->connection->getName();
 
            Log::debug('query : '.$sql);
            Log::debug('time '.$time);
            Log::debug('connection '.$connection);
        });
```

Query

```
StaffRegister::all();
```

Output

```
[2021-03-14 08:00:57] local.DEBUG: query : select * from `staff_registers`  
[2021-03-14 08:00:57] local.DEBUG: time 0.93  
[2021-03-14 08:00:57] local.DEBUG: connection mysql
```

complete structure

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Models\StaffRegister;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
   
       \Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query) {
      
           $sql = $query->sql; 
           $time = $query->time;
           $connection = $query->connection->getName();

           Log::debug('query : '.$sql);
           Log::debug('time '.$time);
           Log::debug('connection '.$connection);
       });

       $obj = StaffRegister::all(); 
    
       return $obj;
   }
}
```

**Accurate Method**

Answer (score 2):

You can use my Laravel package which is work perfectly in Larave 6 and 7. (Not sure about laravel 5 or less.)

For use
**Install the package via composer:** by following command

> `composer require dipenparmar12/laravel-query-log`

restart server.
after this you will see

`storage/logs/db-query.log` file containing your query logs.

For more details visit [Laravel-query-log](https://github.com/dipenparmar12/laravel-query-log)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `::toSql()` or `->toSql()` as demonstrated below:

```
use App\Order;

public function show(Order $order){

    return $order::toSql();
```

Or

```
use App\Order;

public function show(Order $order){

    return $order::where("id", "<>", 0)->toSql();
```

You might have to enable query log:

```
DB::enableQueryLog();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 6+ (i have not checked below 6), you can use

```
// show sql and bindings  +  stop execution
DB::table('your_table')->dd();   

// show sql and bindings
DB::table('your_table')->dump();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#debugging

Answer (score 0):

An easy and quick way I use for check queries during development is to make a voluntary mistake in one of the name of the columns of group or order sentences and then the sql query will be shown on the upper left frame of the debugger window.

It is not perfect because the datetimes are not shown with the "'", but it is easy, fast and doesn't require to add or enable anything additional.