# How to log all Eloquent queries

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slim-3

I'm using Eloquent standalone inside Slim3 framework.
I would like to log all DB queries from Eloquent, I see some implementation but what I'm missing is to log the query when it is made and without an explicit code to insert after each model request.

I found this:
[Laravel Eloquent display query log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140975/laravel-eloquent-display-query-log)
It works, but the best I could get is a Slim middleware that at the end of all request logs at once al queries.

Probably I need a listener, but how can I use it and how get ALL queries?
This is my eloquent bootup inside Slim:

```
$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
    $capsule->addConnection($config['db']);
    $capsule->getConnection("default")->enableQueryLog();
    $capsule->setAsGlobal();
    //$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new \Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher())->listen($events, $listener);
    $capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Comment: The listener only gives you one query at a time. Where do you want to log the queries?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see what is running to DB!

Comment: Do you want to log the queries to a file? Or a database?

Comment: To rolling file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen for query events on the connection:

```
$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection($config['db']);
$capsule->getConnection("default")->enableQueryLog();
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

$capsule->getConnection()->setEventDispatcher(new \Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher);
$capsule->getConnection()->listen(function ($query) {
    // TODO: Log query.
});

$capsule->bootEloquent();
```