# What does a sql query look like when using the belongsToMany method in laravel 6.0?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

What does a sql query look like when using the belongsToMany method in laravel 6.0?

For example, we have three tables in the database:users, roles, role_user.

```
users
+----+-------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+------------+------------+
| id | name  | email           | email_verified_at | password | remember_token | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | admin | admin@gmail.com | NULL              | admin    | NULL           | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | user1 | user1@gmail.com | NULL              | user1    | NULL           | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 | user2 | user2@gmail.com | NULL              | user2    | NULL           | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-------+-----------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

```
roles
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id | name    | description | created_at | updated_at |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | admin   | NULL        | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | user    | NULL        | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 | editor  | NULL        | NULL       | NULL       |
|  4 | manager | NULL        | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+---------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

```
role_user
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
| role_id | user_id | created_at | updated_at |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|       1 |       1 | NULL       | NULL       |
|       2 |       2 | NULL       | NULL       |
|       3 |       3 | NULL       | NULL       |
|       4 |       3 | NULL       | NULL       |
+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Im model User

```
public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
```

What does a sql query look like when using the $this->belongsToMany('App\Role'); method in laravel 6.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Laravel` can easily tell you that.

```
$user->roles()->toSql();
```

For a more comprehensive experience, you can log all queries instead. See this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140975/laravel-eloquent-display-query-log) for more.

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```

Comment: Thanks you 
You helped me a lot