# Laravel returns zero instead of the actual cell value when a parameter passed as an integer

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb, dbal

I have a very simple query from a MariaDB view:

```
SELECT c.amount, c.discount 
FROM factors_view as c
WHERE c.factor_id = 358
```

When I run this query in HeidiSQL I get this result: `amount = 16000, discount = 1200`

But in Laravel 5.7 raw query

```
$result = \DB::select("
   SELECT c.amount,c.discount 
   FROM factors_view as c
   WHERE c.factor_id = 358"
);
```

result: `amount = 16000, discount = 0` and when I put the parameter between quotations:

```
$result = \DB::select("
   SELECT c.amount,c.discount 
   FROM factors_view as c
   WHERE c.factor_id = '358'"
);
```

result: `amount = 16000, discount = 1200`

Type of c.factor_id is `int(10) unsigned`.

This is very strange to me; because the difference is in the query conditions, not the selections!

**The output is the same row with zero value on the specific column!**

Does anyone know what happened?

this is my query logs for both queries:

```
1)
query:"select `c`.`amount`, `c`.`discount` from `factors_view` as `c` where `c`.`factor_id` = ?"
bindings:[0:358]

2)
query:"select `c`.`amount`, `c`.`discount` from `factors_view` as `c` where `c`.`factor_id` = ?"
bindings:[0:"358"]
```

Comment: Can you share the raw queries produced by each of the above? (As described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140975/laravel-eloquent-display-query-log)

Comment: You are selecting the factor_id from the view, Can you select it from the source table without surrounding it with single quote? Does it give you the same results?

Comment: @apokryfos Hi I've edited the post and add query logs.

Comment: I don't know why but despite the fact you've shared a raw unparameterised query, the query logs show a parameterised query. This might explain the discrepancy since there might be an unexpected cast happening somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason for this troublesome error. To correct the error, I changed the type of factor_id in the view:

```
CAST(factor_id AS UNSIGNED) AS factor_id
```

And it's work correctly.

Although the error has been fixed, I still do not realize this behavior. The where condition must affect the rows, not the values of the cells. This may be a doctrine/dbal bug?!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

I *guess* that `factor_id` is `VARCHAR`, when it should be `INT`.

```
int_col = 123     -- can use index
int_col = '123'   -- can use index
char_col = 123    -- 123 dominates; must check all rows, converting char_col to int
char_col = '123'  -- can use index
```