# Laravel Eloquent builder query log

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-7

I have made a [JSON search engine](https://github.com/asseco-voice/laravel-search-query-builder) for our APIs.

The logic for assembling queries is as follows;

Laravel macro is made to enable search method on Eloquent models which creates an instance of the class and runs the search method:

```
/**
 * @var $this Builder
 */
$searcher = new Searcher($this, $request);
$searcher->search();
```

To keep things separated, request parameter classes which have URL query logic are instantiated dynamically and have the same query builder as a dependency. Inside foreach loop the following is executed:

```
new $parameter($this->request, $this->builder, $this->modelConfig);
```

In order to see what was actually searched for, I have set the log to write the actual query and bindings

```
Log::info('[Search] SQL: ' . $this->builder->toSql() . " Bindings: " . implode(', ', $this->builder->getBindings()));
```

Now the issue I'm having is that when loading related models (using `->with()` in one of the request parameters (`RelationsParameter`) that I do get what I asked for, so model is loaded together with relations passed to it, however that is never reflected in the query.

I will always end up with `SELECT * FROM table WHERE something`, without the mention of the related table. Is there a way to get the underlying query as well?

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140975/laravel-eloquent-display-query-log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been digging deeper within Laravel itself, and the answer to the question as why doesn't the `toSql()` method dump the relation SQL as well is because it gets compiled before `eagerLoadRelations` method is triggered.

So currently, it is **not possible** to dump the whole SQL while operating with query builders.

What [halloei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3318377/halloei) suggests will dump all queries executed, however this does not help me at this point because it requires me to add the code outside my package.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your code around Laravel's query logger:

```
\DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
// your code
\DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();
```

After that, you may get the logged queries with `\DB::getQueryLog()`.

However, if you just want to log while developing, I would use the [barryvdh/laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) package.