# Laravel 8 query builder filter results by two datetime columns with whereDate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8's query builder to return a particular result from my database. I've got my query partially working with most of what I need but am having some issues trying to filter based on two particular `datetime` columns.

I've got two columns: `period_from` and `period_to`, I'd like to be able to return the relevant results **after** a given date on the `period_from` column, but before the `period_to` column with a different date, this is what I've got so far:

```php
$events = GoogleAnalytics::where('event_category', $category)
                        ->where('event_action', $action)
                        ->whereDate('period_from', $dateFrom)
                        ->whereDate('period_to', $dateTo)
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->first();
```

This unfortunately doesn't work, I can get results if I drop the `period_to` column, but I need to filter between the two dates. Why isn't this working? Can I have some guidance please? :)

Comment: I think you need something `whereBetween('period_from ', [$dateFrom, $dateTo])`

Comment: Use `where`. As in `->where('period_from', '>=', $dateFrom)->where('period_to', '<=', $dateTo)`

Comment: Neither of the above suggestions work for me. `whereBetween` returns no results, and using the combination of `where` returns the results for just a single day. I need to basically get everything after `period_from` from a given date, to everything up until `period_to` but after `period_from`

Comment: You have first() in your query, maybe that's the reason for single day? Change to get() and check

Comment: I've got `->first()` because I only need the latest result from the returned results

Comment: Well, it doesnt make sense then. Can you share the generated SQL statement then? Enable query log to inspect the query send.. and/or check if the dates align with the records in db. To enable query log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140975/laravel-eloquent-display-query-log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the operators along with the where query.

```
$events = GoogleAnalytics::where('event_category', $category)
                    ->where('event_action', $action)
                    ->where('period_from', '<', $dateFrom)
                    ->where('period_to', '>', $dateTo)
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
   $start_date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date)
                         ->toDateTimeString();

   $end_date = Carbon::parse($request->end_date)
                         ->toDateTimeString();

   return User::whereBetween('created_at', [
     $start_date, $end_date
   ])->get();
```

it helped me , got the information from [this article from codegrepper](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/how+to+filter+between+two+dates+in+laravel)