# Laravel 5.3 - How to log all queries on a page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My team and I are working on a rather big project. There's queries going on everywhere - in controllers, in view composers in views (lazy loading) and probably in some other services as well. It's getting hard to keep a track of it all and the page load speed is fairly slow at the moment.

Where would I put \DB::enableQueryLog() and \DB::getQueryLog() to log ALL the queries and dump them? Basically I'm looking for some place in code that happens before any of the queries happen (to put enableQueryLog()) and I'm looking for a place that happens after the views render (to dump getQueryLog()).

What would be a good way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be you can sore the query in a separate table using getQueryLog() method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the query executed in Laravel 5 ? DB::getQueryLog returning empty array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-arr)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Here comes the perfect example:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#listening-for-query-events

Open **app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php** and add the following to `Boot()` function:

```
DB::listen(function ($query) {
    var_dump([
        $query->sql,
        $query->bindings,
        $query->time
    ]);
});
```

Comment: From my understaning this starts listening to the queries, but where would I dump them? I see the other answer linking to terminable middleware. So a good way would be to implement the terminate() method in a middleware and dump it there?

Comment: You can just Log::info($query->sql)

Comment: So much yes. Easy to implement when needed. Using `\Log::debug('query', [...])` I was able to log everything into the laravel log and find inefficient queries being executed where I could eager load instead. Thank you.

Comment: It does not show where db transaction is started and committed.

Answer (score 19):

You can add this to the Providers/AppServiceProvider.php file and check them in the laravel log file with tail:

```
tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log
```

You can even filter with queries you want to log. For example, here I was using Laravel Passport, and didn't want to log all the oauth queries.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

public function register() {
    if (App::environment('local') && env('APP_URL') == 'http://localhost') {
        Event::listen('Illuminate\Database\Events\QueryExecuted', function ($query) {
            // filter oauth ones
            if (!str_contains($query->sql, 'oauth')) {
                Log::debug($query->sql . ' - ' . serialize($query->bindings));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for `Event::listen`, I got errors in test environment with `DB::listen`

Answer (score 3):

Put this code right above the code where your query is executed

```
\DB::listen(function($sql) {
  die(\Illuminate\Support\Str::replaceArray('?', $sql->bindings, $sql->sql));
});
```

Just modified for executable query:

```
\DB::listen(function ($query) {
   // Enclose in single quotes for string params.
   $bindings = collect($query->bindings)->map(function ($param) {
      if(is_numeric($param)) {
        return $param;
      } else {
        return "'$param'";
      }
   });

   \Log::info(\Illuminate\Support\Str::replaceArray('?', $bindings->toArray(), $query->sql));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print a query which is executed on your app do following steps.

**Step1**: Go to your AppServiceProvider.php file.   // File path App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

**Step2**: Make boot() method and paste below code.

```
public function boot() {
        // Log queries
        if (true) {
            \DB::listen(function ($query) {
                \Log::info(
                    $query->sql, $query->bindings, $query->time
                );
            });
        }
    }
```

**Step3**: Now you can see you queries in lumen.log or laravel.log file. File path is laravel_app\storage\logs\laravel.log or lumen.log.

Enjoy....

Answer (score 1):

add a middleware that executes after the request is done and logs your queries ... see [Terminable Middlwares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#terminable-middleware)

Comment: By that time the queries would have finished since terminable middleware gets called when request is done.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MySQL? You can just tail the log.

[How to show the last queries executed on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650238/how-to-show-the-last-queries-executed-on-mysql)

Or use the Laravel Debug Bar?

Answer (score 0):

Additioanlly There's package available also:

#### log-my-queries

https://packagist.org/packages/technoknol/log-my-queries

Just install and add it's entry to middleware. It will log all the queries in `laravel.log` default log file.