# Get executed sql queries in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to attach executed sql queries to my request. Unforunately my $logs array is empty.

```
$logs = [];

\DB::listen(function ($query) use ($logs) {
   print_r($query->sql); // print_r here works
   $logs[] = $query;
});
print_r($logs); // here $logs is empty
```

Why my $logs array is empty, but inside DB::listen print_r() works? How can I fix it to get my queries in $logs array?

Comment: You could try and use `&$logs` instead of `$logs` in the parentheses after `use`. This way the variable is passed as reference instead of a local copy.

Comment: It doesn't work, array is still empty.

Comment: And when using `global $logs;` inside the function and removing the `use (..)`? Also what does `print_r()` give for just the `$query` variable? Maybe it should be `$logs[] = $query->sql;` ?

Comment: Still empty. Even with global inside and $logs[] = $query->sql

Comment: Can you give some more context of where these lines are in the code?

Comment: I'm testing this code in boot() method of AppServiceProvider, but I also tried in middleware in handle($request, Closure $next) method. In both places result is the same - empty array.

Comment: I'm assuming these lines are all next to each other, so in the same scope?

Comment: Yes, so there is no option to override $logs. Actually you can do the same in middleware or AppServiceProvider -> the result will be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there's a difference in time of execution between the code executed inside the `::listen()` method and the lines before and after.

The code inside will be executed *when a query is sent*, while the other code is performed *on startup of your app*. Thus, after binding the function to the Database facade, no query is executed yet and `$logs` will be empty.

**For logging**

You could try and let the DB listener write the queries to a file or have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27753889/2142071

**For adding to request**

Inside the `listen` method use `request()->request->add(['sql', $query->sql]);` to have the `sql` variable available in the request object.

Comment: I don't want to log them to file. I want to attach all sql queries to request. How can I do that then?

Comment: You might be able to get the current request with the Request facade and then use `$request->request->add(['variable', 'value']);` to add the sql as a request variable or do the same but then with the Response facade (since that is what you're sending back to the browser).