# How to do order by the eloquent query without using join relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to order laravel eloquent query using parent model?
I mean I have an eloquent query where I want to order the query by its parent without using join relationship?
I used whereHas and order by on it, but did not work.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
$query = Post::whereHas('users')->orderBy('users.created_at')->get();
```

Comment: afaik the `whereHas` adds a `where exists` clause in the where without using joins. you could replace the `->get()` to `->toSql()` to see the generated sql query. alternatively, you could use the [`DB` logging function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753868/how-to-get-the-query-executed-in-laravel-5-dbgetquerylog-returning-empty-ar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue why you wanted to order `Post`s based on their `User`'s `created_at` field. Perhaps, a different angle to the problem is needed - like accessing the `Post` from `User` instead.

That being said, an [`orderBy()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderBy) can accept a closure as parameter which will create a subquery then, you can pair it with [`whereRaw()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereRaw) to somewhat circumvent Eloquent and QueryBuilder limitation*.

```
Post::orderBy(function($q) {
    return $q->from('users')
      ->whereRaw('`users`.id = `posts`.id')
      ->select('created_at');
})
->get();
```

It should generate the following query:

```
select *
  from `posts`
  order by (
            select `created_at`
            from `users`
            where `users`.id = `posts`.id
           ) asc
```

A join might serve you better, but there are many ways to build queries.

*As far as I know, the subquery can't be made to be aware of the parent query fields

Answer (score 2):

If you want to order `Post` by a column in `user` you have to do a join in some way unless you sort after you retrieve the result so either:

```
$query = Post::select('posts.*')
             ->join('users', 'users.id', 'posts.user_id')
             ->orderBy('users.created_at')->get();
```

Note that `whereHas` is not needed anymore because the join (which is an inner join by default) will only result in posts that have a user.

Alternatively you can do:

```
$query = Post::has('users')
    ->with('users')
    ->get()
    ->sortBy(function ($post) { return $post->users->created_at; });
```

The reason is that eloquent relationships are queried in a separate query from the one that gets the parent model so you can't use relationship columns during that query.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `orderBy` in your `Post` model.

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, "user_id")->orderByDesc('created_at');
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```php
Post::query()
  ->has('users')
  ->orderBy(
    User::select('created_at')
        ->whereColumn('id', 'posts.user_id')
        ->orderBy('created_at')
  )
  ->get();
```

The sql generated would be like

```sql
select * from `posts` 
    where exists (select * from `users` where `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`) 
    order by (select `created_at` from `users` where `id` = `posts`.`user_id` order by `created_at` asc) asc
```

But I guess join would be a simpler approach for this use case.

[Laravel Docs - Eloquent - Subquery Ordering](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#subquery-ordering)